# Remove the spacing between items of etaremune

Tags: lists

Is it possible to remove or reduce the spacing between the items listed by the package `etaremune`? Something similar to `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}

\begin{etaremune}
    \item Third item
    \item Second item
    \item First item
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `etaremune` you can use some keys similar to the ones of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{etaremune}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
    \item Third item
    \item Second item
    \item First item
\end{etaremune}
Some text after
\end{document}
```

[image]

> "One can also change the style of all etaremune environments throughout the document by specifying these options in the `\usepackage` command."